# Fetch sender details for bitcoin transaction

Tags: php, api, blockchain, bitcoin, bitcoind

I am trying to get sender address for a bitcoin transaction. Is it possible?
I found many articles saying it is not possible to get the sender address, I'm not sure how the blockchain.com is displaying the sender as well as receiver address?
I tried getting details using listtransaction as well as gettransaction using my transaction ID but It is returning only receiver address.

Can someone help me please?
[Reference Image from blockchain.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur6QQ.png)

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you want to get the data? What software are you trying to use?

Comment: @JBaczuk Thanks for your response. 
I am not using any software, I am trying to get the sender details using PHP API call. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to get the information from blockchain.com api or Bitcoin core JSON RPC, or something else?